# Gridview doesn't update when the bound data changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I've bound my data grid and a bunch of check boxes to the following properties in my view model (typed *Presenter*).

```
public ListCollectionView AllOrdersView { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<CarrierType> AllCarrierTypes
{
  get { return _allCarrierTypes; }
  set
  {
    _allCarrierTypes = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

In the constructor of it, I assign a filter like so.

```
public Presenter()
{
  _allOrders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(DataAccessor.GetOrders());
  AllOrdersView = new ListCollectionView(_allOrders);
  AllOrdersView.Filter = element => AllCarrierTypes
    .Where(x => x.Active).Contains(((Order)element).CarrierType);
}
```

The aim is to filter off the orders that have a carrier of type that's unchecked. At the moment, it seems that the filtration only takes place initially, as the constructor is invoked. My hope was that, since the check boxes are bound, I need no further intervention with the code. It's not the case. As I select/deselect the check boxes, the data grid stays unaffected.

Furthermore, suspecting that it's got to do with the need to refresh the view, I added a call to the view as follows.

```
private void ToggleButton_OnUnchecked(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  ((Presenter)DataContext).AllOrdersView.Refresh();
}
```

Sadly, that doesn't seem to make any difference and I'm all stuck. So, my questions are these.

1. Do I need to refresh explicitly in the event handler at all?
2. Do I need to add another (kind of) binding?
3. Do I need to implement anything more in the view model?

My bindings are done in the following way.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCarrierTypes}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                IsChecked="{Binding Active,Mode=TwoWay}"
                Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked"
                Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllOrdersView}"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" .../>
```

## Edit

Per requestion - full version of the *CarrierType* class in the model.

```
public class CarrierType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private bool _active;

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public bool Active
  {
    get { return _active; }
    set
    {
      _active = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public override String ToString()
  {
    return Name;
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's seems to be a problem with the *ListCollectionView* in .NET 4.5 (not sure if the problem existed earlier). You would need to call *Refresh()* but it doesn't seem to work.

What I do is to re-assign the filter.

```
private void ToggleButton_OnUnchecked(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  AllOrdersView.Filter = element => AllCarrierTypes
    .Where(x => x.Active).Contains(((Order)element).CarrierType); 
}
```

As requested in the comments below :

```
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Active,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to some kind of documentation of it? Are there any others way to work-around it? Is there any chance that it's **intended** behavior and that we just misuse it? Also, I notice that you omitted the part referring to the view model instance through *DataContext*. Is that possible? I always go through that, cast and then refer to it, which is inconvenient.

Comment: MSDN : "Re-creates the view. "

Comment: I just crossed paths with this issue multiple times , i would love to find out i'm mistaken .

Comment: You might actually be onto something, so +1. When I set the filter to null in my event handler, I get the difference in the data set shown. However, it seems not to follow the selection of the check boxes. Suggestions?

Comment: Yes that's a different question . 
Checked and Unchecked are different events in WPF CheckBox

Comment: @KonradViltersten I didn't understand .. "seems not to follow the selection.."

Comment: Sorry, mate. I mean that I've bound the checkboxes to *AllCarrierTypes* so that their on/off state is bound to *Active* property in the model (see the code in my question). However, it seems that this binding doesn't work. Can you verify that the binding is correctly done?

Comment: post your model , 'CarrierType'

Comment: Maybe the problem is UpdateSourceTrigger , try setting it to PropertyChanged 

UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged , 
I couldn't find meta data info for this on MSDN for some reason , 
i usually check stuff like this with Reflector ..

Comment: Can you elaborate that, please? Where exactly does the suggested change go? XAML? View model? I did this: *IsChecked="{Binding Active,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"* but it gave no difference...

Comment: Binding has a property called UpdateSourceTrigger , set it through XAML ,

Comment: Yeah, like I showed in my comment, right? Sadly, it didn't work. What more can I do to trouble-shoot it?