# Binding of a check box doesn't transport the values to the model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, data-binding

I've created a list of check boxes and bound them as shown below.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCarrierTypes}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                IsChecked="{Binding Active,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked"
                Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However, when I breakpoint on the unchecked event and see the contents of *AllCarrierTypes*, using *Where()* to only get the actives, I see that the list stays the same, despite the fact that those small thingies in the GUI actually are on and off. What can I do to troubleshoot it? According to the things I've read and seen, it supposed to work, so it's likely something stupid I've forgotten...

Comment: Have you tried a simpler example? `<CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Active}"/>`? What do those event handlers do?

Comment: Please post your view model code.

Comment: I was told that, it needed to be a two-way because I'm reading in values in the itnitializer setting the boxes. And specifying update source trigger was suggested as a possible remedy in another thread (where I asked about another issue, which seems to be dependent on this one). The handlers are there because the data grid needs to get the filter set explicitly (some issue in .NET, according to [some guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28003429/1525840)).

Comment: @dymanoid Is there anything specific you'd like to verify there? I've posted it already in [another thread's edit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28003262/1525840) and it feel to me like spamming SO with it.   :)

Comment: You should not rely on the order in which things happen here. Although your Unchecked handler is called, the `IsChecked` binding to the respective view model item might not have been triggered yet. Remove the Checked and Unchecked handlers, and move their code to the setter of the `Active` property in your view model. Or at least ode the view model related code to the view model.

Comment: @Clemens I haven't tried that, yet. While moving the code, I realized that I know of no reference to the instance of the *Presenter* (my view model) in the model class. Is there a neat trick to obtain it somehow or do I simply need to send it over from the main class or such? Without it, I don't know how to set the filter of the view in the view model upon the property being changed.

Comment: Perhaps the filter should also be a property in your view model.

Comment: @Clemens I'll try to do that. But it seems to me like a very lousy design. And a lot of dependencies back and forth for something as basic as filtering a grid by a selection of a check box... Either I'm approaching it from wrong angle or the data binding and view model isn't such a great idea as indicated.

Comment: @Clemens I've just rechecked the whole description of M-V-VM paradigm. It's against all its idea to provide a reference of the VM to the M from V, isn't it? V and M are not supposed to talk to each other at all! And since the instance of VM is created in the V, it's from there it would come. I have a strong impression that it's how the binding is done that's the problem. But I get stuck on how to resolve or trouble-shoot it...

Comment: Did you debug the binding to see it get and set are called?

Comment: @Blam I've tried but the code in the end got so messy... As far I could see, I get the setters hit **but** the value changed didn't caused the update as wanted. I even offered to pay a guy to solve it but he couldn't. Well, as long as the checkboxes were of fix number he could. But mine are created by a template. I'm suspecting that the issue is too complicated to be resolve on SO.   :(